# Is Bootstrap confidence intervals equivalent to the confidence intervals computed with the same number of redraws from the population?

Tags: bootstrap

Suppose we have a sample of size n from a population and we wish to estimate the a confidence interval for the mean of this sample. bootstrap method does that by taking resamples with replacement from this sample M times and uses the variation among them to build CIs.
Now suppose instead of taking these resamples from the given sample, we can somehow take new samples (of size n) from the population itself and use those as the basis for calculating CIs.
My question is: Do these two methods give the same answer? Are there any scientific references for the second method?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the same answer"?  This might sound like a strange request, so let point out that *of course* the results differ, because your original sample will not be exactly the same as the population.  But if you were to repeat the *entire* process, going back to take a new sample and bootstrapping that, and did that many times, there would be clear *long run, average* relationships between the results of the two approaches.

Comment: You are right. What I mean by the same answer is the following two:
1- Does the "standard deviation" around the mean asymptotically converge to the same value in those two methods?
2- Is the rate of convergence equal between the two?

note that my focus is on the standard deviation, not the mean itself. As you mentioned, the mean of the sample could differ from the mean in the population, but is it true for the standard deviation as well?

Comment: Re asymptotically: please distinguish asymptotics in $n$ from asymptotics in $M.$  The only relevant one is the first, because $M$ is merely part of a *computer procedure* to *approximate* the true bootstrap distribution.  And, for all the same reasons I gave earlier, the SD of the sample will differ from the SD of the population and so the bootstrap estimate of the SD will differ from that of the population and will vary from on sample of the population to the next.

Comment: I am interested in asymptotics in M. I don't follow why it isnt relevant. As far as I know, bootstrap SDs converge to the true SDs of the mean as M grows. If M didn't matter, why even take more than 2 resampls? I think maybe the confusion comes from the way I described the second method. The samples we redraw from the population is not the same size as the population, but the same size as the original SAMPLE. so the only difference between the two methods is instead of redrawing samples of size n from the original sample of size n, we redraw samples of size n from the population of size N).

Comment: So even in the second method, the mean of a sample is not necessarily the mean of the whole population, but with infinite redraws, it converges to it, whereas in the bootstrap approach, in infinite redraws the mean converges to the mean of the sample, which is different from the mean of population itself. But I was not sure about standard deviations.

Comment: The same holds for virtually any statistic, for all the same reasons.

Comment: Thank you. As for the last part of the question, have you ever seen a research paper following the second method I outlined here?

Comment: The second method (resampling from the population) is described in most introductory statistics textbooks.  It is, of course, conceptual rather than practical.